# How to decorate a table cell with a JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

How to use javascript to decorate a cell in html?

I have this table in html

```
<table border="1" width="300" height="200">
        <tr>
            <td id="11"><</td>
            <td id="12"></td>
            <td id="13"></td>
            <td id="14"></td>
            <td id="15"></td>
            <td id="16"></td>
            <td id="17"></td>
            <td id="18"></td>
            <td id="19"></td>
            <td id="20"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px solid grey;>
        }
    </style>
```

I want to conditionally get cell id 11, and paint it black

I tried to do it on JS, but nothing worked

```
function bthClick(){
    let table = document.querySelectorAll('td id')
    table[11].style.color = 'dark'
}
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see what is wrong? On the console you shoel see that table isn't set. The format you have given will look for all elements with a td tag and then look for any of  their descendants that have an id tag. Learn about querySeletorAll at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/queryselectorall

Answer (score 0):

To get the cell with id 11 use `document.querySelector('td[id="11"]')`, And Note that dark is not a valid color value in `CSS`, use black instead.

```js
function bthClick() {
  // select the cell with id "11"
  let cell = document.querySelector('td[id="11"]'); 
  
  // set its background color to black and text color to white
  cell.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; 
  cell.style.color = 'white'; 
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="bthClick()">Decorate Table</button>

<table border="1" width="300" height="200">
        <tr>
            <td id="11">11</td>
            <td id="12">12</td>
            <td id="13">13</td>
            <td id="14">14</td>
            <td id="15">15</td>
            <td id="16">16</td>
            <td id="17">17</td>
            <td id="18">18</td>
            <td id="19">19</td>
            <td id="20">20</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Since IDs have to be unique, we can even just use document.getElementById("11"); no need for querySelector.

Comment: @Jake your comment makes no sense. Why not use `querySelector()` method? Do you know the difference between the latter and `getElementById()` ?

Comment: Why doesn't my comment make sense?  We have a list of elements with unique ids.  Using getElementById in this case is perfectly acceptable; querySelector is heavier-duty than we really need.  If you'd like an objective reason, then getElementById is generally faster than querySelector, so you should use getElementById for performance reasons if nothing else.

Comment: Or if you are really dead-set on querySelector, then querySelector("#11") would be better as well.